# Django - validate model before saving to DB

Tags: python, django, validation

in Django 1.10 -
I want to create multiple objects by importing - I'm uploading a file with data and creating objects with the given data. Before creating them I want to validate fields to make sure as much as I can that creation will pass successfully and collect as much data as I can about invalidate fields. For example, to find out whether a char field is too long. 
I can use 'if' statement for each field but it's not robust.
I thought of using the model Serializer. The problem is that there are models to create that uses other models that also should be created. So when trying to validate the model that depends on the other one - it fails since it's not existed yet.

For example:

```
class FirstModel(BaseModel):
  title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
  identifier = models.CharField(max_length=15)

class SecondModel(BaseModel):
  identifier = models.CharField(max_length=15)
  firstModel = models.ForeignKey(FirstModel, related_name='first_model')
```

I think that my question is actually - 
How can I validate only part of a model fields before creating it on DB?

Comment: Why can't you use the standard Django validation methods, which are well documented?

Comment: can you please elaborate?

Comment: What do you mean with "creating multiple objects by importing"? What is the workflow that you are trying to do?

Comment: @Bob - added information - I'm basically uploading a file with data (csv, xls) and creating objects with the given data

Comment: Right, so you are uploading the file to the Django server?
In that case I would recommend what Daniel also said, I think that the validations that Django will do cover all of what you need. You can just create all the models, when the models are created the validations will be done immediately, after that you call `.save()` to actually store them in the database.

Comment: @Bob- thanks for the answer. First of all - how do you suggest to create the models? .create() will also run 'save()', and running something like 'FirstModel(title=" ", identifier=" ")' will not run validations. I tried running 'clean_fields' or 'serializer.is_valid()' but the problem is, as mentioned in the question is that it also validates the related object, which is not created yet so validation fails.